# Find all objects and reapply current styles in Silverlight/XAML

Tags: silverlight, xaml, styles

I'm working on customizing the appearance of a silverlight app on user-click and with some help have managed to swap out the Resource Dictionary and reapply a style to a button - where the reapplied style comes from the new Resource dictionary. This works but I need to make it scalable, since the whole app needs to be restyle with a single user click.

I reapply the style of the button with the following statement:

```
this.button1.Style = (Style)App.Current.Resources["ButtonTheme"];
```

The two things I want to do are:

1. Get a collection of all objects on the page (all buttons, text boxes everything)
2. Loop through them and reapply whatever is the object's current style (after swapping out the Resource Dictionary)

Help here greatly appreciated.  Also, please tell me if there is a better approach altogether.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the "old" theme from the resource dictionary and then merge in the new one
See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229724/change-theme-at-runtime) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16916393/silverlight-app-change-styles-on-user-click/16932669#16932669)

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a much better way to do it.  I'm having another problem tho - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16987902/applying-custom-theme-in-silverlight

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do it manually.

Please take a look at this sample http://weblogs.asp.net/lduveau/archive/2010/05/31/dynamically-apply-and-change-theme-with-the-silverlight-toolkit.aspx